# How to set a specific time for editing in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google file with 5 sheets. 4 of them are dedicated to be filled by specific people (1 person fills his own sheet but hasn't any access to others') and the 5-th one is for calculating the total from these 4.

So the goal is to set a specific time when these spreadsheets could be filled. Let's say every Friday from 9 am to 6 pm. How can I do this part?

I am really new to GAS

Comment: Put a timer on your sheet protection

Answer (score 0):

### Use Time-Driven Triggers

There is a feature in Google Apps Script wherein you can set the exact time wherein a function can be triggered.

### Script

You can use the following code as the basis for your script:

```
const users = ["user1@gmail.com", //user1
  "user2@gmail.com", //user2
  "user3@gmail.com", //user3
  "user4@gmail.com"]; //user4

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
const sh3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
const sh4 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");

function enableUsers() {
  sh1.protect().removeEditors(users).addEditor(users[0]);
  sh2.protect().removeEditors(users).addEditor(users[1]);
  sh3.protect().removeEditors(users).addEditor(users[2]);
  sh4.protect().removeEditors(users).addEditor(users[3]);
}

function disableUsers() {
  sh1.protect().removeEditors(users);
  sh2.protect().removeEditors(users);
  sh3.protect().removeEditors(users);
  sh4.protect().removeEditors(users);
}
```

### Set the Time-Driven Triggers

To add time-driven triggers, go to the `triggers` tab.

[image]

For enabling the sheets, set `enableUsers` to be triggered every `friday 9am to 10am`.

[image]

For disabling the sheets, set `disableUsers` to be triggered every `friday 6pm to 7pm`.

[image]

### References:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have other questions.